# AWS ALB redirect to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-elb

My Apache servers are behind an ALB/ELB.  I'm terminating SSL at the load balancer.  The load balancer listens on both 80 and 443.  I want to redirect all http requests to https.

I have this rewrite rule in place in the vhost config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

This works, but the issue is that I also have redirects in an htaccess file.  When a redirect happens through the htaccess file, it redirects to http first and then the vhost config redirect picks it up and redirects to https.  I want to eliminate the extra http redirect.

http://mysite.example.com/sub
301
https://mysite.example.com/sub
301
http://mysite.example.com/newsub  - this redirect is htaccess
301
https://mysite.example.com/newsub
200

I'd like to gracefully get around having the htaccess redirect to http first.  I can get around this by adding https://%{HTTP:Host} to rewrite rules.  Is this the best way to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^sub$ https://%{HTTP:Host}/newsub [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If you have access to .conf files, you shouldn't be using .htaccess at all

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about just having a .conf file with the redirects and then doing an include in the vhost config.  My goal is to make the redirect file simple for my users.

Answer (score 27):

Application Load Balancer now supports two new actions: redirect and fixed-response. You can configure these actions as part of the content-based routing rules, enabling you to offload this functionality to the load balancer. This simplifies deployments while benefiting from the scale, the availability, and the reliability of Elastic Load Balancing.

Here's what I did to make it work on AWS:

[Example configuration for ALB redirection - HTTP -> HTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eNWM.png)

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/elastic-load-balancing-announces-support-for-redirects-and-fixed-responses-for-application-load-balancer/

Comment: I am not sure why but this redirect isn't available in dropdown on our newly created ALB.

Comment: @Jangid - Can you share more information, please? Which region? LB type? Creation method? Also, please share a screenshot.

Comment: I fiddled with it for sometime and the redirect option started to appear. Probably it was some JavaScript cache issue.

Comment: Okay, yeah maybe.

Answer (score 16):

If your web servers are running behind an **AWS Application Load Balancer** and you configured at least one listener for HTTP port 80, you can redirect http to https directly by doing this:

1. Go to **EC2 Console**, then **Load Balancing** and **Load Balancers** from left menu.
2. Click on your ALB name checkbox, then select **Listeners** Tab. If you create two listeners for HTTP and HTTPS go to step 4.
3. If you did not set a HTTPS Listener on Load Balancer's first creation, then click on **Add Listener**. Choose *HTTPS* and *Port* (443 usually). In **Default action(s)** select **Forward to...** option and then your **Target Group** for your Load Balancer. **Weight** it's ok in 1. Choose the appropriate **Security policy** and then add your **Default SSL certificate** for your case (you must have a ssl certificate registered on **AWS Certificate Manager** or **AWS IAM**). Then click on **Save**. Test your settings going to https://load-balancer-dns-name or https://your-server-dns-name
4. To configure HTTP redirection, select the HTTP:80 checkbox and click on **Edit** button. In the **Default action(s)** click the *thrash* icon to remove ***Forward to*** current setting. Then click on **Add** action and select **Redirect to** option. Common values for this section are *HTTPS*, *443* port, *Original host, path, query* and *301 - Permanently moved*. Finally, click on **Update** button at the right top of the page.
5. Now test going to http://load-balancer-dns-name or http://your-server-dns-name and you will be redirected to HTTPS.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I was having a lot of issues with NGINX location redirects as a lot of people recommend, and this was quick to implement and works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much, no need nginx config. since already use ACM