# Configure https on multiple port in AWS beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two docker containers in beanstalk instances, One listen on port 80, another one listen port 8080. The security group allows port 80,8080. I can access url on port 80 and 8080 using http. I want to use https. I have created a certificate in ACM. Updated the load balancer in beanstalk env as below. but now i can not access website using https.[ImagePorts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9nPS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to https listener in your Load balancer, from the image the protocol is https but the port is `80`

- Create an https listener in LB
- Map `443` of LB with `80` of the target
- allow `443` in the SG of LB

instance port should be `80`. As the SSL traffic decrypt before sending to the target.

[image]

If you are interested to add SSL with `8080` then you need to specify certificate[image] with `8080` as well.

Comment: Yes, that worked well for port 80, Is there anyway I can access port 8080 as well on https

Comment: yes all you need to specify a certificate for `8080` in the listener of ALB.

Comment: I have one more question regarding the scenario. Https working fine on port 80 and port 8080. Now I want to redirect all http request to https. I have added below lines in apache virtual conf file.
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http  
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]  
This works fine on port 80 and it redirect to https. But while accessing site like http://example.com:8080, this dose not work well and getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I think this is because listener on port 8080 not defined. Any workaround for this?

Comment: you can redirect in LB, so you do not need to configure it in appache config. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065056/aws-alb-redirect-to-https

Comment: Its a classic load balancer. Redirection is possible in Application load balancer. Looks like redirection is not possible in Classic Load balancer. I followed this link
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Not sure if any workaround possible in CLB.

Comment: no its not possible in classic load, you to handle at application level.

Comment: or add application LB at the backend of classic LB and use the ALB for redirect purpose.